# Why does this ip route/rule work with ssh but not with http/https?

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, https, http

I am operating a server that is connected that has an active OpenVPN client. To allow SSH access into the server, I added another secondary IP address to the server's WAN interface (eno1), and then executed these commands in descending order :

```
ip route add default via (secondary IP GW) dev eno1:0 table 1234
ip rule add from (secondary IP/NETMASK) table 1234
ip addr add (secondary IP/NETMASK) dev eno1:0
```

This setup works fine with SSH, because I can access the server using the secondary IP by SSH, and I can even ping it using the same secondary IP as well.

The problem is, when I attempt to access a web server hosted on the same host (on docker), the connection times out. However, when I disconnect the OpenVPN client, it works fine again. I have no active firewalls configured on this server.

Below is an truncated output of the command `netstat -plnt`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1852/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2615/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1852/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2615/dockerd
```

I want to know why I experience connection timeouts when I try to connect to my server using HTTP/HTTPS when the connection works fine with SSH.

Also, would there be additonal rules/routes or IPTables rules I can add to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use the alias naming scheme with the `ip` tool.
- Don't use the mask in the rule, otherwise you will get strange behavior.
- So, you need use commands like these:

```
ip route add default via <ip-gw-secondary> dev eno1 table 1234
ip rule add from <2nd-ip> table 1234
ip addr add <ip-2nd>/<pref-len> dev eno1
```

- How do you specify the usage of the secondary ip in your programs? You should use an option to specify the source address.
- If your setup doesn't work when openvpn is active, you should check the actual routing in this moment with command `ip route get <dst> from <ip-2nd>`.